# QGIS different results between $length and measuring in the map

Tags: qgis, measurements

I use QGIS Lisboa and need the length of some shapefiles. When I use the field calculator the results are always around 30% higher than in real, also than a measuring in the map.

Does anybody have a similar problem or knows about a solution?

Comment: Which CRS are you using?

Comment: By "length of some shapefiles" do you mean the length of all features in each shapefile? I assume you are dealing with LineString features.

Answer (score 2):

Field calculator uses the CRS of the shapefile, while measurement tool uses the projects CRS, until you uncheck `Use ellipsoid`

The two CRS may be the same, or not.

You can right-click on the layer `-> Set Layer CRS for Project`, unless you are using openlayers plugin for background layer.